# Define an xsd:list where each item must be unique?

Tags: xml, list, xsd, schema, set

Is it possible express in XML Schema a simple type which is a list *and* which has the further restriction that each item in the list may only appear once? Said differently, is it possible to define a "set" simple type in XML Schema?

For example, using the following schema:

```
<xs:schema version="1.1" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="item">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="itemSet">
    <xs:list itemType="item"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="set" type="itemSet"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This document validates:

```
<root set="A B"/>
```

However, so does this document, **which I would like to fail validation** because `B` is repeated:

```
<root set="A B B"/>
```

I suspect this is not possible with XML Schema alone, but I don't know it very well so I am looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible in XSD 1.0, but it's very easy in XSD 1.1:

```
<xs:simpleType name="uniqueList">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKENS">
    <xs:assert test="count($value) = count(distinct-values($value))"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a processor that understands 1.1 (oops! Thought I did.) Also NMTOKEN is too restrictive regarding start-character. I think I would have to make an `itemList` type with the `xs:list`, and then *another* `itemSet` type with the `xs:assert` restriction, correct?

Comment: Yes, of course you can substitute your own user-defined list type for xs:NMTOKENS in this example.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible through regular expression. It could be much easier if we enforce the attribute value to be ordered. If not we probably have to create 'N' pattern expression with all combination

```
  <xs:simpleType name="itemSet1">
<xs:restriction base="itemSet">
 <xs:pattern value="(A\s?)?(B\s?)?(C\s?)?"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

```
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="set" type="itemSet1">
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Now

```
<root set="A B A"/>
```

is invalid and so is

```
<root set="B A"/>
```

If you want the above one to be also valid we need to add another pattern to the restriction with this order.

Comment: Requiring a specific order is too restrictive for my particular case, sorry, but it might help other people to know about this option.

Comment: This solution relies on the list being constrained to a small enumeration of strings - which was true of the example given, but not of the general problem.